# How to dynamically build queries with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PDO and want to do something like this:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM :table WHERE :column = :value");
$query->bindParam(':table', $tableName);
$query->bindParam(':column', $columnName);
$query->bindParam(':value', $value);
```

Will PDO allow me to bind the table name and the column name like this? It *seems* to allow it, but it puts quotes around my parameters even if I use PDO::PARAM_INT or PDO::PARAM_BOOL as the data type.

If this won't work, how can I safely escape my variables so that I can interpolate them in the query?

Comment: A prepared statement is a query who's path has been analyzed. You can't analyze a query with no table or even column information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't bind parameters by column names.

What you could try is to dynamically create your SQL command:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE $columnName = :value";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':value', $value);
```

Just make sure to sanitize your parameters/variables if they are coming from elsewhere, to prevent SQL Injection. In this case, `$value` is safe **to a degree** but `$tableName` and `$columnName` are not -- again, that is most especially if the values for these variables are not provided by `you` and instead by your users/vistors/etc...

One other thing; please avoid using `*` and name your columns instead... See some reasons why:

http://www.jasonvolpe.com/topics/sql/

[Performance issue in using SELECT *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487578/performance-issue-in-using-select)

See other similar posts here:

[Why doesn't binding parameter in ORDER BY clause order the results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907687/problem-binding-parameter-to-pdo-statement)

[How do I set ORDER BY params using prepared PDO statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542410/how-do-i-set-order-by-params-using-prepared-pdo-statement)

Comment: So what is the proper way to escape things in PDO? It seems like PDO::quote() is not what I want.

Comment: You can take a look at the following: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php or http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php (among other ways to validate your inputs). People say it's okay `not` to escape parameters when binding using PDO's `bindParam` or `bindValue` since the value is being 'bound' as a value and not something to be interpreted as anything else, but I **`highly recommend`** that you sanitize/validate all input coming from your user. That includes querystrings.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if using something like mysql_real_escape_string will work cross-database or if there was a more generic function to use.

Comment: In PHP, you can still use: [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) or you can use regular expressions if you want to customize how you validate your data. :)