# PHP LIKE query keeps turning up empty

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-like

For some reason my PHP PDO sql search isn't turning up anything. I'm trying to implement some kind of search engine into my site, but I can't seem to get anything. I've been trying a bunch of different solutions up until now but the search keeps turning up empty, even given exactly the right parameters.
The $find variable is entered by the user, and the $field variable is a dropdown list from which the user can choose what to search for, which returns values that equal the names of columns in the database.

```
            $find = strtoupper($_POST['find']);
            $find = "%" . $find . "%";
            $field = $_POST['field'];

            $qry = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM \"MovieDB\" WHERE upper(:field) LIKE :find%");
            $qry->bindParam(':find', $find, PDO::PARAM_STR, 16);
            $qry->bindParam(':field',$field, PDO::PARAM_STR,16);
            $qry->execute();
            $results = $qry->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Typo in query? `:find%<<<--`

Comment: Try `upper(:field) LIKE :find` (no trailing `%`).  The percentages are bound by the parameter `$find`.

Comment: Nope, the trailing % was a typo indeed, but removing it didn't solve it.

Comment: I don't think you can bind field (or table) names. You may need to inject those values directly into the query. But be sure to sanitize! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314043/how-to-dynamically-build-queries-with-pdo

Comment: Yay! Thanks showdev, you can put that as an answer, because it worked! A thousand thanks to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO does not allow binding of field or table names.

I suggest injecting the field value directly into your query string.
Be sure to sanitize it to avoid SQL injection!

```
$qry = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM \"MovieDB\"
                       WHERE upper(`".$field_santizied."`) LIKE :find");
$qry->bindParam(':find', $find, PDO::PARAM_STR, 16);
```

[How to dynamically build queries with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314043/how-to-dynamically-build-queries-with-pdo)

php.net references inability to bind table names:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304