# How To Use Variables In Mysql Queries With PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to use my variables in my mysql queries safely. Im using pdo for this. But i can't use pdo placeholders for table name.

This works;

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($id));
```

But this doesnt;

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($table, $id));
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You can't use placeholders for table/field names - you already answered that in the question... you need to interpolate them into the string; see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314043/how-to-dynamically-build-queries-with-pdo

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute($id);
```

You can't use placeholders for table

That should not be a problem since the table name should be something you control.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i was using this already. just i want find something new.

Answer (score 0):

here is the simple answer for you.

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=(:some_id)");
$statement->execute(array(':some_id' => $row['id']));
```

you should provide it with key => value format.

Comment: what is the reason for voting it down.