# RedBeanPHP: Values in Find don't work

Tags: php, orm, redbean

I used the example below to order the results in my Table however the orderby variable doesn't seem to effect the order of results. I can't get access to the underlying SQL Query to see what RedBean is doing and I have checked and $sortorder and $sort are the correct values.

```
$needles = R::find('needle',
    ' haystack = :haystack ORDER BY :sortorder :sort', 
        array( 
            ':sort' => $sort
            ':sortorder'=>$sortorder, 
            ':haystack'=>$haystack 
        )
    );
```

Comment: Is that really your query?  You have a table named 'needle' with a column named 'haystack'?

Comment: Yes I have set up a table so I can get my head round Redbean but the Order BY Command dosn't have any effect

Comment: Edit your post and display the `var_dump($needles);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But, you can easily prepare your query string before :

```
$query = sprintf('ORDER BY %s %s LIMIT :size', $column, $sortOrder);

$items = R::find(
    'item',
    $query,
    array(
        'size' => (int) $size
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameter binding is meant for values, the order-by clause uses columns and SQL statements.

RedBeanPHP relies on PDO parameter binding which is great for (among other things) preventing SQL injections.

Here is discussion about the limitations of PDO parameter binding in PHP:
[Why doesn't binding parameter in ORDER BY clause order the results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907687/why-doesnt-binding-parameter-in-order-by-clause-order-the-results)