# Is building queries with binding parameters in PDO injection safe?

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo, code-injection

This is the query I am preparing. This looks too much like a normal mysql_query and I am unsure if I am out of the safe boundaries of PDO.

```
function opinionlist($orderby="dateposted desc",$page="0",$pagesize="10"){
  $dbh = new PDO(...);
  $s = $dbh->prepare("select * from fe_opinion 
                       order by :orderby limit :page,:pagesize");
  $s->bindParam(":orderby", $orderby);
  $s->bindParam(":page", $page);
  $s->bindParam(":pagesize, $pagesize");
  $s->execute();
  $opinionlist = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  echo json_encode($opinionlist);
}
```

1. Can I safely build queries like this?
2. Is getting a table name for an order by statement safe or should I
   **ONLY** get values from input?

currently I changed my code to

```
function opinionlist($orderby="dateposted desc",$page="0",$pagesize="10"){
  $orderbylist=array("dateposted desc","countcomment desc","countvote desc");
  $dbh = new PDO(...);
  if(!in_array($orderby, $orderbylist)){$orderby="dateposted desc";}
  $s = $dbh->prepare("select * from fe_opinion order by $orderby limit :page,:pagesize");
  $s->bindParam(":page", $page);
  $s->bindParam(":pagesize, $pagesize");
  $s->execute();
  $opinionlist = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  echo json_encode($opinionlist);
}
```

Comment: This might not actually work for the `LIMIT`.  Parameters do not replace variables for concatenation. You could do `LIMIT :offset, :limit` but you can't replace the whole LIMIT clause with a single parameter.

Comment: @Michael I changed the page parameters, my query is still getting table name for the order by statement. Is getting something other than a value injection safe?

Comment: You can't "bind" column names. That wouldn't be a prepared statement, but make it dynamic again.

Comment: I checked the docs and didn't find specific info but this question seems to indicate a bound param won't work as an order by table either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542410/how-do-i-set-order-by-params-using-prepared-pdo-statement

Comment: I would suggest splitting up the `$orderby` parameter into the column name and a boolean for ascending and descending. This will make it easier to validate. However, have you considering using an existing PHP ORM to construct queries?

Comment: @MichaelMior Yes I made an array of accepted values for that parameter in second code block. and about ORM, no. I recently gave up on object oriented programming in favor of my precious programming time. I dont play legos anymore and I am totally fine with it.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan Why does OOP take more time?

Comment: @MichaelMior http://www.geocities.com/tablizer/oopbad.htm#gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice to validate the type and contents of your inputs.

You can sanitize `$orderby` with `mysql_real_escape_string()` or reject values for `$orderby` which don't consist of a single valid column name followed by an optional `asc` or `desc` (or even a comma separated list of these, if you wish).  You could determine your list of valid columns either by hard coding or requesting a list of columns for that table (from INFORMATION_SCHEMA).

And of course you can use `is_numeric()` for `$page` and `$pagesize`.

With that in place, not only are you covering against sql injection, but also making your code more robust.

---

Small update: as you discovered, you can't use a parameter for `$orderby`.

Comment: There's no need to escape values when using prepared statements via PDO. PDO handles this automatically.

Comment: @MichaelMior pdo only escapes bound parameters.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan The updated code you posted is a nice clean way to validate your input - it gets my vote.