# Dynamic column list in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make a simple search-function that's going to select and show everything, from a column.

```
if(isset($_GET["search"]) && ($_POST["filter"] != "all")) {
    $filter = $_POST["filter"];
    $sql = "SELECT :table FROM johnson LIMIT 0,30";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":table", $filter, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

This snippet seems to work just as it should.

Then I'm trying to display the data:

```
<?php } else if($filter != "all") { ?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["$filter"]; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php 
}
```

`$filter` corresponds with the proper database column, like if `$filter == 'email'`, it should be `SELECT email FROM johnson`.

The result? After querying the database, it just loops the column name like:

```
email
email
email
email
```

And not `foo@bar.com`, etc. Whats wrong? Using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

It even works when hardcoded, and not using `:table`.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that is a limitation of prepared statements.

If you bind a variable it will effectively be seen on the other end as a string - that's why your result is always "email" instead of the email coloumn.
The same reason is behind why you [cannot use a variable for the `order by` field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542410/how-do-i-set-order-by-params-using-prepared-pdo-statement).

Comment: So there's no workaround? i simply have to have 1 query for each column? like "SELECT email FROM...", "SELECT employee FROM..." and so forth? :/

Comment: @DreamHawk No, just list your columns like `SELECT email, foo, bar FROM table`.

Comment: Okay, i made a simple switch-case, switch($filter) - email -> SELECT email FROM..., And that worked! Thanks :)