# PDO in codeigniter, unable to bind params

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

I am having the following problem:

**Environment** PHP, codeigniter framework with PDO.

**my code**

```
public function index(){

        $sql = "SELECT ........ LIMIT ?,?";

        $q = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        $limit = 0;

        $offset = 10;

        $q->execute(array($limit, $offset));           

        $r = $q->fetch();

        var_dump($r);

    }
```

**problem**: There is no problem in the sql query as, if i hardcode any integers (e.g. 0, 10) in the LIMIT clause; the query returns the desirable result. **The problem occurs only when binding the params**.

**Error shown** dumping the $r in above code returns **bool(false)**

**Now, the following code runs successfully,**

```
public function index(){

        $sql = "SELECT ........ LIMIT 0,10";

        $q = $this->db->prepare($sql);           

        $q->execute();           

        $r = $q->fetch();

        var_dump($r);

    }
```

what can be the problem in the former code while binding? Am i doing it wrongly or could there be chance that it is creeping up due to codeigniter not supporting PDO by default?

Comment: I might be wrong but you don't bind LIMIT (nor column names) but only values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set ORDER BY params using prepared PDO statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542410/how-do-i-set-order-by-params-using-prepared-pdo-statement)

Comment: @DamienPirsy: you are right. I checked with other clauses and found the difference. My bad, i thought the limit and offset in that clause as values. I guess i'll need to pass it directly and use my own validation. thanx for the quick comment

Comment: @itachi: Please add your solution as an answer (yes you can answer your own questions) - and accept it. This will mark your question as solved. Or if the question is invalid, you can delete it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As adviced, I am putting my own answer.

**You can't bind variables to LIMIT or ORDER by clause**

SOLUTION:

Pass it as a variable in the sql query (And probably sanitize with **intval** just to be safer.)