# PDO prepared statement with conditions not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to to get my data from MYSQL using PDO but I am not having any luck.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$postQuery = $DBH->prepare("SELECT title, views, rating, thumb FROM posts WHERE category=:category and status=1 ORDER BY :sort DESC");
$postQuery ->bindParam(':category', $category);
$postQuery ->bindParam(':sort', $sort);
$postQuery ->execute();
```

This works without errors but it returns all of the posts in alphabetical order, ignoring the category and the sort.

I tried this:

```
$postQuery = $DBH->query("SELECT title, views, rating, thumb FROM posts WHERE category={$category} and status=1 ORDER BY {$sort} DESC");
```

This did work but I don't get the protection of the prepared statement. Any ideas on why one statement works but the other one does not?

Answer (score 3):

Your bound parameter `:sort` gets expanded to a string literal, not a SQL identifier.  That is, you are effectively evaluating something along the lines of:

```sql
ORDER BY 'rating' DESC
```

Since literals like this are constant for every record, it has no effect on the order of the resultset.

You can't parameterise identifiers, so must concatenate that part of the SQL into your prepared statement (the safest way is to set `$sort` from a predetermined set of safe values, based on whatever logic is appropriate to your needs).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use place holders in ORDER BY clauses. See this question: [How do I set ORDER BY params using prepared PDO statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542410/how-do-i-set-order-by-params-using-prepared-pdo-statement)