# Order by PDO+mySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to get the last row inserted into the database, but only get the first row. How I can fix it?

In phpmyadmin everything works:
[image: phpmyadmin]
But the code does not work:

```
Último precio: 28.41
```

Code:

```
            $skip = 0;
            $max = 1;
            $id = 'gooo_id';
            $q = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM price WHERE asin = :asin ORDER BY :id DESC LIMIT :skip, :max');
            $q->bindValue(':asin', $asin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue(':skip', (int) trim($skip), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $q->bindValue(':max', (int) trim($max), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $q->execute();
            $result_row = $q->fetchObject();
            $lastprice = $result_row->price;
            echo 'Último precio: '.$lastprice.'';
```

---

**Solution**

```
$skip = 0;
            $max = 1;
            $q = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM price WHERE asin = :asin ORDER BY gooo_id DESC LIMIT :skip, :max');
            $q->bindValue(':asin', $asin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue(':skip', (int) trim($skip), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $q->bindValue(':max', (int) trim($max), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $q->execute();
            $result_row = $q->fetchObject();
            $lastprice = $result_row->price;
            echo 'Último precio: '.$lastprice.'';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542410/how-do-i-set-order-by-params-using-prepared-pdo-statement

Comment: I don't think you can pass field names with bindValue. In your case field is converted to string so 'gooo_id'

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the attribute name from SQL table after `ORDER BY` in your query. You put in the value as argument which is the same for all rows. Thus it doesn't do anything with  the order.

The query should be something like:

```
$q = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM price WHERE asin = :asin ORDER BY gooo_id DESC LIMIT :skip, :max');
```

Of course you need to adjust the bind variables...

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in...

Comment: Delete the line `$q->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);`