# MariaDB error with query

Tags: mariadb

I'm getting following error when executing query .

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '25'' at line 1
```

here is the query

```
   $sqlData = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id_id = :UID_ID ORDER BY :ORDER_BY :ORDER_TYPE limit :START, :DATA_LENGTH';

        $params = array(
            ":UID" => $uId,
            ":ORDER_BY" => $orderBy,
            ":ORDER_TYPE" => $orderType,
            ":START" => $start,
            ":DATA_LENGTH" => $length
        );
      $queryData = \registry::getDBHandler()->prepare($sqlData);


  $queryData->execute($params);
var_dump($queryData->execute($params));
```

## note

here is the var dum output of paramas

```
array (size=5)
  ':UID' => string '66' (length=2)
  ':ORDER_BY' => string 'id' (length=2)
  ':ORDER_TYPE' => string 'asc' (length=3)
  ':START' => string '0' (length=1)
  ':DATA_LENGTH' => string '25' (length=2)
```

Comment: I don't think you can use prepared variables with ORDER BY or LIMIT.

Comment: @RocketHazmat : is there any other way to do this ? pls advice

Comment: Where are your `$params` coming from?  Especially the `$orderBy`, `$orderType`, `$start` and `$length`.  You're going to have to *manually* append those values to the query, so you're also going to have to correctly escape them.  Or rather, do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2543144 Where you have a hard-coded set of values you can use and only use it if it's in the list (or for the LIMIT just make sure they are numbers).

Comment: @ Rocket Hazmat its from my dataTable 
        $orderByColumnIndex  = $formData['order'][0]['column'];
        $orderBy = $formData['columns'][$orderByColumnIndex]['data'];
        $orderType = $formData['order'][0]['dir'];
        $start  = $formData['start'];
        $length = $formData['length'];

Comment: Ok, so those aren't entered in by the user?  Then you'll need to *manually* append them into the query string and only have `$uId` in your `$params` array.

Comment: In fact, you can use all of them except for `ASC` in a prepared statement.

Comment: @Rocket Hazma " you meant something like this 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id_id = :UID_ID ORDER BY $orderBy $orderType limit $start,$length' ? pls advice

Comment: @Tharuperera: Yes, except use *double quotes* instead of single quotes.

Comment: I rolled back the question and answers since it did not make sense without the statement.  If you need to delete the details, at least show us the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepared statements let you bind variables to the `WHERE` (and I think `SELECT`) clauses of an SQL query.  Unfortunately, they do not let you bind to the `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` (or `FROM`) clauses.  For that, you will need to *manually* append to the string.

Since those values are not being entered by the user, you should be safe from SQL injection if you just do:

```
$sqlData = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id_id = :UID_ID ORDER BY $orderBy $orderType LIMIT $start, $length";
```

<sub>(Note the double quotes around the string)</sub>

And then your `$params` array would just be:

```
$params = array(":UID" => $uId);
```

---

If you are worried about SQL injection, then you can use the following to help with that:

- For your `ORDER BY`, you can make sure that your `$orderBy` is in a *hard-coded* list of fields and reject it if it is not.
- For `$orderType`, just simply ensure it is equal to either `"asc"` or `"desc"` (possibly ignoring case).
- With `$start` and `$length`, make sure they are *integers*.  You can also try to use `intval()` to convert them if need be.

If you follow these rules, then it should be safe to append these variables into your SQL query.  Since `$uId` is part of the `WHERE`, you can use the prepared variable for it and that is fine.