# Why it shows me error when preparing a sentence in PHP with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm creating a sentence prepared in PHP, and I run into a rare syntax error, I do not know if it is breaching any of MySQL or why I show that error

The syntax is as follows, I want to sort by row and by ascending or descending type and limit the results

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY ? ? LIMIT? ,?"

if($conn->prepare($query)){ .. } // error
```

The error is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '? LIMIT ? , ?' at line 1

If you execute said statement in MySQL, it correctly throws the results

Comment: have you bind the parameters to query?

Comment: @Sachin the linking is not done, if it is not prepared correctly the error is not the binding.

Comment: After the order by you give two "?" and after the limit need space between limit and "?"

Comment: Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542410/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters to `ORDER BY` are not values, and cannot be parametrised. One is a column reference, the other is a keyword.

Comment: What would be the best way to add the order by in terms of security to the query. Concatenating?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Make _very_ sure your concatenated snippet is not user-submitted, or is properly validated.

Answer (score 0):

For example do like this and try.
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY column_name LIMIT 0,10";